# I'm trying to generate allure report for gradle IntelliJ project through terminal command. Its showing loading for long, other menu showing 404 error

Tags: java, selenium, gradle, testng, allure

After Tests run with first command, I just ran last report command to view report. I'm new to this allure report and can someone help me on this?

**Project Details**

Gradle:       7.2

Kotlin:       1.5.21

Groovy:       3.0.8

Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9

JVM:          17 (Homebrew 17+0)

OS:           Mac OS X 10.15.7 x86_64

```
- ./gradlew clean RunSequentialTests -Dtag=### -Dcountry=ID -DslackNotif=consumer-### -DnoOfRetries=5 --stacktrace

- ./gradlew allureReport
```

Latest Report image
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use direct Allure's command:

```
allure serve /path/to/target/folder/in/your/project/
```

Comment: What path should i add along with allure serve cmd?

Comment: By default, test results are being stored in /project-root/target/allure-results

Comment: okay. I tried below command after some research and its showing some old report but not the latest one. `allure serve allure-results`.

Comment: Lets say its showing 9/27/2021 report and not the one which i ran. Can you help me on this?

Comment: Try to navigate to your project directory, completely remove `target` folder, run tests and then run `allure serve target/allure-results`

Comment: Yes it worked. It's looking for allure results path to view correct allure report. I ran allure serve command with exact allure-results path which is created after test run. Thanks!